# How do I stop HiveServer2 from automatically starting as a daemon?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, thrift

I'm trying to run a HiveThriftServer2 programmatically via the `org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext()` method, but I can't create a socket on the port because there's already a HiveServer2 running there. The server re-starts if I kill it, too.

```
$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep 9999
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3325/java 


$ ps -ef | grep 3325
hive      3325     1  2 10:29 ?        00:00:07 /usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk  
/bin/java -Xmx1000m -Dhive.log.dir=/var/log/hive -Dhive.log.file=hive-  
server2.log -Dhive.log.threshold=INFO -server -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr  
/lib/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr  
/lib/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str= -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console  
 -Djava.library.path=:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop  
/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml  
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/log/hive/tmp  
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender  
-Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=30 org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar /usr/lib/hive/lib  
/hive-service-1.0.0-amzn-0.jar org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2  
 --hiveconf hive.aux.jars.path=file:///usr/lib/hive/auxlib/emr-ddb-hive.jar,  
file:///usr/lib/hive/auxlib/emr-hive-goodies.jar,  
file:///usr/lib/hive/auxlib/emr-kinesis-hive.jar
hadoop    5048 11886  0 10:34 pts/1    00:00:00 grep 3325
```

How can I stop this from happening, so that I can start my own ThriftServer programmatically?

Comment: use this command `sudo kill -9 3325`

Comment: I tried that before, but it seems to be automatically restarted. For context, there's no relevant file in /etc/init.d/.

Comment: You can try to restart you hadoop cluster or stop your yarn service. may be it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

On EMR 3.x.x AMI's ,

`ls /etc/init.d/` can tell you that there's `hive-serverd` script used to stop/start/restart HS2 daemon.

To stop/start/restart HS2, You can do

```
sudo service hive-serverd restart
sudo service hive-serverd stop
sudo service hive-serverd start
```

---

On EMR 4.x.x & 5.x.x AMI's ,

Service management is handled by upstart, and not the traditional SysVInit scripts. Services can be queried using the upstart commands found in [upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/)

**List of services on EMR:**

```
grep -ir "env DAEMON=" /etc/init/ | cut -d"\"" -f2

hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
oozie
hadoop-hdfs-namenode
hive-hcatalog-server
hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver
hue
hadoop-kms
hadoop-yarn-proxyserver
hadoop-httpfs
hive-server2
hadoop-yarn-timelineserver
```

**example commands to stop/start HS2:**

```
status hive-server2
sudo stop hive-server2
sudo start hive-server2
sudo reload hive-server2
```

---

Comment: Supa, I cannot find any reference online on how EMR4+ changed the way hive server2 inits. you answer is really help! Thanks!

Comment: @jcmannem, just curious, is there any specific reason the new EMR does not use the newer `systemd` but choose `upstart`?